# React Native: unhandlepromiserejectionwarning : Error: Couldn't start project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
09:57:00: Restarting packager...
09:57:00: Error parsing JSON file: SyntaxError: Expected '}' instead of EOF at l
ine 10 column 1 of the JSON5 data. Still to read: ""
Building JavaScript bundle [                                               ] 0%(
node:6700) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Couldn't start project. Plea
se fix the errors and restart the project.
    at C:\xdl\src\Project.js:1317:11
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\user\React Native Apps\TheGoldenRule2\node_modules\xdl\bui
ld\Project.js:1710:191)
    at C:\Users\user\React Native Apps\TheGoldenRule2\node_modules\xdl\build\Pro
ject.js:1710:361
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
(node:6700) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection
 id: 4)
09:57:21: Finished building JavaScript bundle in 34634ms
```

I'm running react-native 0.52.0 and Expo 25.0.0. I tried to integrate Google Firebase into my project as well. I just recently just got this error when I tried to restart the packager to check if one of my image assets would download. The project itself is loading onto Expo Client but I feel like this is an issue that might bite me back later in development. Is there anyway to solve this?